# Get Version Number of WSO2 Identity Server from Carbon Admin Portal

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2's Identity Server.  I would like to know the current version of my Identity Server so I can see if [this pull request](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth/pull/995) should be in my version.

Is there a way to see the version of WSO2's Identity Server from the Carbon Admin Portal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the Mgt console using `https://<host>:<port>/carbon` URL and click on the orange colored **Identity Server** logo in the top to get the index page with the version details.

For example, below server is 5.10.0
[image]

Also, the version is mentioned in the `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/carbon.xml` file as below.
`<Version>5.10.0</Version>`

Comment: Thank you!  For those that follow after, this only showed up when I logged in with the `admin` account.  My user is in the admin role, but that was not enough.  (It only showed Host and Server URL for my user.)  Moral of the story, only the admin account is actually admin.